# mysql select to give all rows of one column that match any row of another?

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------------+
| orders_total_id | orders_id | value |    class    |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|               1 |         1 | 34.00 | ot_subtotal |
|               2 |         1 | 8.56  | ot_shipping |
|               3 |         1 | 2.38  | ot_tax      |
|               4 |         1 | 0.600 | ot_tax      |
|               5 |         2 | 45.54 | ot_subtotal |
|               6 |         2 | 8.56  | ot_shipping |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to show ALL the records that belong to ANY rows which also have a row that has class=ot_tax.  So in the above, rows 1-4 would match because one (or more) of them have a class of ot_tax and they all have the same orders_id, but NOT rows 5-6 because they also have same orders_id but none have class=ot_tax.

I want to say the key here has to do with grouping, but SQL syntax still feels so foreign to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe it has to do with joining itself?  Hmm

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE class='ot_tax'`?

Comment: But that shows me only orders_total_id 3 and 4 in the example above.

Comment: Curious:  why'd my question get a -1?

Comment: @bcsteeve Who knows why it got down voted; maybe someone thought it was boring or not researched enough, or was just having a bad day. Compared to many questions yours was clear so I wouldn't worry too much about it. It's just imaginary internet points in the end.

Comment: But those are MY imaginary internet points!  lol.  No, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get all orders that have a row with `class='ot_tax'` ?

There are several ways, for instance using the `in` predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE orders_id IN (SELECT orders_id FROM table_name WHERE class='ot_tax')
```

Comment: Perfect!  Well, almost... slight typo (missing s from second orders_id).  I'd like to understand WHY it works.  I'll have to investigate what IN does.   I keep forgetting about sub-queries.  Thanks!

Comment: @bcsteeve The query should be pretty easy to understand. The subquery returns a set of orders_id such that all fulfill the class condition and the `in` checks that the orders_id in the table are members in that set.